# Как реализовать фильтрацию по дереву в Ext js?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Есть Tree Panel
в него я добавл поле для фильтрации

```
xtype: 'triggerfield',
    listeners: {
        change: function() {
        console.log()
    }
}
```

не могу разобраться, как отправлять запрос на сервер с вводимым значением из поля. То есть я ввел в поле что-то, он отправил запрос, там отфильтровал и вернул мне ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что в вашем вопросе не хватает версии ExtJS для начала. Потому как начиная с версии Ext JS 5.0 используемый вами класс `triggerfield` устарел. Рекомендую использовать `Ext.form.field.Text` для ваших нужд - просто текстовое поле.

Касаемо `Ext.tree.Panel` - он предоставляет древовидное представление пользовательского интерфейса данных. `TreePanel` должен быть привязан к хранилищу`Ext.data.TreeStore`. Фильтрацию данных можно делать как в самом дереве с помощью `queryBy`, так и в хранилище (это если локально делать фильтрацию без запроса на сервер, что работает быстрее).

Касаемо запроса на сервер, думаю вам нужно в хранилище прописать `proxy`, в котором указать как минимум `url` откуда будут браться данные. А также указать `autoSync` в `true` чтобы автоматически синхронизировать хранилище по его прокси после каждого редактирования.

Хотел написать комментарий, но он не помещается, поэтому дал ответ. В общем, основываясь на том, что у вас есть в вопросе - ответ будет таким (содержащим советы, без чего-то конкретного, если еще что-то вспомню - напишу). Советую дополнить вопрос более полным кодом.

Хороший ресурс для черпания информации: [Sencha Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/)